# How to read URL from Urban Airship push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

In my Android project i am trying to send push notifications using Urban Airship Rich Composer. I receive the notifications successfully and i am also able to perform actions when the notification is clicked.

However, I am also sending a URL with the message in the UA Rich Composer. How can i read this URL in my broadcast receiver function? Is there a  way to fetch it from the intent? Following is my code code snippet:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED))
    {
        // Push received
    }
    else
    if (intent.getAction().equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED))
    {
    // Push opened

    Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
        launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mukul

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send extra data through an urbanairship push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418936/how-do-i-send-extra-data-through-an-urbanairship-push-notification)

Comment: @Eran that question does not have an answer

Comment: http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic_guides/android_deep_linking.html

Comment: deep linking worked! thanks!